# How to check if url is tel: or javascript: type

Tags: php, regex, url, hyperlink

i curl a URL and detect all links but i have a problem it also detect tel:, JavaScript:, Skype:, chrome:, sms: and ...

I try below code to check if URL is proper or not, but this is too long code and also not include all possibility.
so i want to use regex but it not working

```
<?php   
if($url==''){echo 'error';}                                                 // ignore self and blank links
else if(substr($url,0,strlen('#'))==='#'){echo 'error';}                        // ignore hash-tag links
else if(substr($url,0,strlen('javascript:'))==='javascript:'){echo 'error';}   // ignore script links
else if(substr($url,0,strlen('data:'))==='data:'){echo 'error';}                // ignore base64_decoded files
else if(substr($url,0,strlen('chrome:'))==='data:'){echo 'error';}              // ignore chrome links
else if(substr($url,0,strlen('mailto:'))==='mailto:'){echo 'error';}            // ignore email links
else if(substr($url,0,strlen('tel:'))==='tel:'){echo 'error';}                  // ignore mobile calls links
else if(substr($url,0,strlen('sms:'))==='tel:'){echo 'error';}                  // ignore SMS links
else if(substr($url,0,strlen('callto:'))==='callto:'){echo 'error';}            // ignore skype calls second method links
else
{
    echo $url;
}
?>
```

```
<?php
$url=$_GET['url'];
if(preg_match('^(?:[a-z]+:)?//',$url))
{
    echo 'error';
}
else
{
    echo $url;
}
?>
```

I expect if URL is tel: or sms: or chrome: or something like this it should be print "error" else it should be print given URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you have to use [delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

The code in your example says if there is a match for `^(?:[a-z]+:)?//` which will match for example `a://` or `http://` and will then echo error because `[a-z]+` is a very broad match.

What you could do is use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!` to assert what is directly on the right is not one of the listed options.

If that assertion passes, match any char 1+ times `.+` to prevent matching an empty string.

```
^(?!(?:javascript|data|chrome|mailto|tel|sms|callto|mms|skype):).+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SX9Te3/1)

For example

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
if (preg_match('/^(?!(?:javascript|data|chrome|mailto|tel|sms|callto|mms|skype):).+$/', $url)) {
    echo $url;
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your reply and solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if starting with `http` like this:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
if (preg_match('/^http/', $url)) {
    echo $url;
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,
but please check again my code i required for ignore only chrome: tel: sms: mms: skype: like this expect https://, http://, ftp:// , // and also without scheme like "../../hello.html"

Comment: replace `preg_match('/^http/', $url)` to `preg_match('/^(!?chrome:|tel:|sms:|mms:|skype)(.*)/', $url)